# How to get value in my show page in Grails

Tags: grails

How to get the value as following codes with my show view page on Grails?

**Person.groovy**

```
package com

class Person {

    String person

    static constraints = {
        person blank:false,nullable:true

    }
    static hasMany=[task:Task]
    String toString(){return person}
    static mapping={
    }
}
```

**Task.groovy**

```
package com.moog

class Task {

    String task

     static constraints = {
        task blank:false,nullable:true,unique:true

    }
     static belongsTo=[person:Person]
     static hasMany=[tag:Tag]
     String toString(){return task}
}
```

**Tag.groovy**

```
package com

class Tag {
    String tag


    static constraints = {
        tag blank:false, nullable:true

    }
    static belongsTo=[task:Task]
    String toString(){
        return tag
    }
}
```

Comment: please add more specific content with your problems

Comment: i have  have three classes i.e person,task and tag .person having many tasks and task having many tags.i got three i.e person,tag and task values on my list view and create view but it does not shown view on my show file.why?

Comment: Please provide more information & code. Like how are you saving the instance? Is the instance persisting to the database? Can you see values in your database? How your show page is being rendered?

Answer (score 1):

First of all try a better wording for your collections

```
static hasMany=[tasks:Task]  // in Person.groovy

static hasMany=[tags:Tag]    // in Task.groovy
```

In your person show.gsp try something like

```
<g:each in=${person.tasks} var="task">
  <p>${task}</p>
</g:each>
```

If you do not use scaffolding and write you own controller methods to create your entities than maybe this helps you further:

```
def task = new Task(task:"Clean room")
def person = Person.get(1)
person.addToTasks(task)
person.save()
```